# Error in codeigniter

Tags: php

I am encountering this error. I have deployed my project from localhost to server every thing else is working fine just getting this error.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: try http://www.unixmen.com/solved-php-warning-module-pdo-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0/